# Correct or rewrite/redesign code?

Tags: discussion

Some questions is about code not working as expected, i.e. OP provides some code which doesn't generate the expected result and ask for help figuring out the problem. Some times (well, often) such questions are asked by inexperienced programmers (students, maybe) and the provided code may be badly designed.

For such questions I'm wondering what type of answer to give?

a) Point to the actual bug (e.g. use of uninitialized variables)?

or

b) Propose a (complete) rewrite using a better design (e.g. use standard containers instead of user defined types)

I've seen both types of answers.

I kind of prefer a) as this will help OP learn a specific item (e.g. always initialize before use) and the code will end up doing the right thing even though it could have been achieved in a "better" way.

Are there any general SO guide for this? What do you think?

Comment: The very best answers do both, but just posting completely new code without any sort of explanation is not really useful to the OP -- I'd consider it worse than answers that just point out the most obvious bugs in their code.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

If we imagine a question that is about some SQL error but the OP also introduced a major SQL Injection Attack opportunity I think we all agree you should fix both.

So you address the original issue and provide guidance on the other issues with the code. And these have to be major issues that have a general consensus that they shouldn't be present in production code. So don't go fixing your own weird naming convention.

Based on the amount of code you would need to write you can decide to only provide a small example that demonstrates what needs to be fixed and leave the rest to the OP. If that would be too much you could add a link to a post that addresses the other issues.

You create a win-win if you can fit a solution in a comprehensive and complete answer that is clear and understandable. If the answer is useful for future visitors but also addresses all concerns in the code of the OP your answer is ready for upvotes.